# Accessing Tabular Data on Snakemake

Tags: python, linux, config, bioinformatics, snakemake

Essentially, I want to be able to access metadata from tabular data in my config file. For now I'm doing something simple, like accessing whether the Layout of the sample is SE or PE and printing that into a text file, and later on I will do something a little more complicated. However..... I'm not sure why I am getting an error, here is what I have so far..

I have tabular data that looks like this, named sample.tab:

```
Sample  Layout
SRR11213896     SE
ERR3887380      PE
```

And this is my config file, config.yaml:

```
sample_file: "sample.tab"
```

And this is my Snakefile:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
import pandas as pd
sample_file = config["sample_file"]
samples = pd.read_table(sample_file).set_index("Sample", drop = False)
 
rule all:
        input:
                expand("{sample}.txt", sample=samples)
rule rule1:
        output:
                "{sample}.txt"
        params:
                tag = lambda wc: samples[samples.Sample == wc.sample].Layout[0]
        shell:
                """
                touch {output}
                echo {params.tag} > {output}
                """
```

The error:

```
InputFunctionException in line 11 of /Dir/Snakefile:
IndexError: index out of bounds
Wildcards:
sample=Sample
```

I want my output to be 2 text files: SRR11213896.txt containing "SE", and ERR3887380.txt containing "PE".....

I've been stuck on this for hours.. anyone have any ideas? It would be so greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a problem here:

```
expand("{sample}.txt", sample=samples)
```

because `samples` is a dataframe. Maybe you want:

```
expand("{sample}.txt", sample=samples.Sample)
```

also, for debugging add a `print` statement to see if the dataframe is correctly processed:

```
samples = pd.read_table(sample_file).set_index("Sample", drop = False)
print(samples)
```

Comment: This looks right to me. I might suggest leaning into your sample index more (and letting `drop=True` in the `set_index()` call). You can expand using `expand(..., sample=samples.index)` and you can access your data directly later with `.loc`. EG: `tag=lambda wc: samples.loc[wc.sample, 'Layout']`